# How can I place `throw` inside helper-functions but still have null-safety?

Tags: kotlin

I want to wrap a `throw` in a helper-function, for logging purposes and such.

```kotlin
private fun chooseEmailAddress(user: UserProfile): EmailAddress {
    val emailAddress = user.emailAddresses.find {
        true // some business logic
    }
    if (emailAddress == null) {
        throwAndNotice(CustomError(
            message = "No Email Address found.",
        ))
    }
    return emailAddress
}

private fun throwAndNotice(err: CustomError) {
    NewRelic.noticeError(err)
    throw err
}
```

The problem:`kotlin` complains about a type-mismatch:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Email
Found: Email?
```

I guess the compiler does not know that `throwAndNotice` always throws. If I inline the `throwAndNotice` method, it works, but it leads to duplication in about a dozen methods.

Is there a way I can tell the compiler "the following method always throws"?  Or is there another idiomatic way to deal with this issue? I don't want to resort to `!!`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it return `Nothing`. This indicates that it will never return (either throw an exception or infinite loop):

```
private fun throwAndNotice(err: CustomError): Nothing {
    NewRelic.noticeError(err)
    throw err
}
```

You can see other examples of doing this in the standard library, like [`TODO()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-t-o-d-o.html) and [`error()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/error.html).

Side note (as mentioned by dey in the comments):

The null check can be rewritten using `?:` like this:

```
return emailAddress ?: throwAndNotice(...)
```

Comment: You can add here, that the code can be simplified by using elvis operator to replace if: `return emailAddress ?: throwAndNotice(...)`